# change directory in os.system

Tags: python, os.system

How should I use os.system to run script for several directories. 
I tried this:

```
listofdirnumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(listofdirnumbers)):
    os.system("script.py 'arg1 "mydir_%d"%i arg2 '")
```

But it gave me the error of invalid syntax.

Another question how does it work if I want to input several arguments - is this correct?

```
(os.system("script.py 'arg1 arg2 arg3'"))
```

Comment: What is `mydir_`? is that supposed to be inside the string? Double check your quote marks.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean run a script for several directories as well? Is a directory/directory's contents the input?

Comment: mydir_ is some directory so it should look like: mydir_01 then mydir_02 etc.

Comment: yes, in these directories there are my input files. So the script takes one directory and all the files inside this directory ... runs ... and then it skips to another directory.

Comment: ... I have no idea what you are doing with `listofdirnumbers`... why do you even define it?

Comment: btw: use args without quotas `os.system("script.py arg1 arg2 arg3")`. With quotas in `os.system("script.py 'arg1 arg2 arg3' ")` `script.py` will treat `'arg1 arg2 arg3'` as one long argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you wish to execute including arguments should be passed as a string. There is no such concept as nested string like `"script.py 'arg1 "mydir_%d"%i arg2 '"` in Python.

```
listofdirnumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(listofdirnumbers)):
    os.system("script.py arg1 mydir_%d arg2" % i)
```

Multiple arguments can be passed like

```
os.system("script.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

Comment: ok this worked finally, thanks, I made some stupid things on the way and these quotes are very confusing for me as a non-programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the double quotes inside your double-quoted string. You probably wanted to write something like:

```
os.system("""script.py 'arg1 "mydir_%d" arg2 '""" % i)
```

Or, escaping the double quotes:

```
os.system("script.py 'arg1 \"mydir_%d\" arg2 '" % i)
```

Even though the double quotes are actually useless in this circumstance...

I don't really know why you are adding the single quotes inside that command. The single-quote delimited string would be considered a *single* argument. In the example `script.py` will receive *one* argument of the form `arg1 "my_dir_N" arg2` where `N` is an integer. If you want to pass more than one argument to the program *don't* group them with single quotes.

Also you should *avoid* `os.system` altogether. The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module provides a much *safer* and more flexible interface.
The code using `subprocess` would be:

```
import subprocess

for i in listofdirnumbers:
    subprocess.call(['script.py', 'arg1', 'my_dir_%d' % i, 'arg2'])
```

(this will provide *three* arguments to `script.py`).